# Get custom Magento attribute value for calculation

Tags: php, magento

On the Magento product page I need to construct a value of a price per piece. The product is sold as a pack of an X amount. For example I buy 1 pack of coffee cups. The pack contains 100 cups and is (tier)priced as $10. The price per piece would be $0.10 (tier price / amount per pack). For this I'm configuring the /product/view/attributes.phtml template by adding a fixed row to the table.

What would be the best way of retrieving the custom attribute (amount_per_pack) together with the tier price of the product?

Comment: how about do this the other way around?  Set the products price per single unit - so $0.10, and then on the product page, check to see if the attribute amount_per_pack has a value > 1 and if so, change the quantity selector to a drop down of attribute_per_pack x1, x2, x3 etc

Comment: Good thinking, however we need to work with data coming from the ERP system, so we it's the above mentioned procedure we'll have to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've managed solving the issue already ourselves. In case someone else needs such a solution I'll post the answer:

Using the attributes.html template you already have pretty much all product attributes at your disposal. First we call for the pack amount:

```
<?php $_packamount = $_product->getPackAmount(); ?>
```

Then call for the tier price

```
<?php $_tierPrices = $_product->getTierPrice(1); ?>
```

Putting it all together by dividing the tier price by the pack amount:

```
<?php $_pieceprice = $_tierPrices / $_packamount; ?>
```

And echo the result back into the template:

```
<?php echo (round($_pieceprice,2)); ?>
```

Pretty simple and straightforward